# Soma de números em um intervalo C++

Tags: c++, soma

Preciso fazer um programa com uma função recursiva que recebe como parâmetros dois números inteiros `n` e `m`, onde `n <= m` e retorna a soma dos números neste intervalo.

Por exemplo, se `n = 1` e `m = 4` então o resultado seria `10`: `1 + 2 + 3 + 4`.

Porém preciso de ajuda por ser iniciante em programação.

Eu cheguei a fazer o seguinte código:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int somanm(int n,int m){
    int s = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= m; i++ )
        s = (i(i+1))/2;
    return s;
}
int main(){
    int n, m, s, resul;
    cin >> n >> m;
    resul = somanm(n,m);
    cout << resul;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para entender melhor como resolver o problema, recomendo ler mais sobre [recursividade](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursividade_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)). A definição de recursividade pode ser entendida **como uma sub-rotina (método ou função) que pode chamar a ela mesma**. Para o problema apresentado, uma possível solução utilizando recursividade seria:

```
int somanm(int n, int m) {
    // Inicialmente, inserimos n + 1
    int soma = n + 1;

    // Caso o mesmo seja menor ou igual a m, podemos prosseguir com seu resultado
    if (soma <= m) {
        // Retornando o valor com a próxima chamada para a mesma função, que vai receber n + 1.
        // Isso pode ser entendido como "andando um item para frente", dado que
        // n + 1 está mais próximo de m do que apenas n.
        return soma + somanm(n + 1, m);
    }

    // Caso não esteja dentro das condições, retornamos apenas 0.
    return 0;
}
```

Chamando a função já adicionando o `n`, visto que o mesmo é inclusivo:

```
resul = n + somanm(n, m);
```

O resultado da função `somamn` para os dados `1` e `4` seria:

```
1
4
10
```

Answer (score 2):

[Função recursiva da cauda](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursividade_(ci%C3%AAncia_da_computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)#Fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es_recursivas_em_cauda):

```py
// n <= m
int somanm(int n, int m) {
    if (n == m) return n;
    return somanm(n, m - 1) + m;
}
```

outra função recursiva:

```py
// n <= m
int somanm(int n, int m) {
    if (n == m) return n;
    int i = (m + n) / 2;
    return somanm(n, i) + somanm(i+1, m);
}
```

Mas as funções recursivas preenchem [pilha de chamada](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilha_de_chamada) e é melhor usar [a progressão aritmética](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progress%C3%A3o_aritm%C3%A9tica) neste caso:

```py
// n <= m
int somanm(int n, int m) {
    return (n + m) * (m - n + 1) / 2;
}
```